# How to create a Parser rule for unmatched or partial tokens in Antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I have [this grammar](https://github.com/obiwanjacobi/Zingularity/blob/master/Source/Language%20Server/server/src/z80asm/z80asm.g4) (starts at line 109) that is used in an IDE to gather information about the source code file being edited (its Z80 assembly)

I need to trigger a parser rule or have a robust way to interpret the parse tree (ErrorNodes) to detect incomplete / partial text being typed in by the user.

I have added a 'partial' parser rule that catches all characters using an ANY token defined at the bottom. However this doesn't work.

I also tried looking at the parse tree to see if there is some way to write logic (in my listener) to lift it out, but it seems that the new partial text sometimes does not even show up in the parse tree...

Answer (score 1):

that sounds like an island grammar. The usual procedure (see, e.g., "Separating XML Islands from a Sea of Text" in ANTLR 4 book) is to have a lexer grammar file with valid tokens first and then a catch all. Seems you've done that so maybe use the intellij plugin to see how it is tokenizing the input.  The grammar rules will have to allow lots of junk if it's incomplete as you suggest. Oh, you need the catchall in the lexer not the parser. Be careful not to use `.+` in the parser. It'll consume everything. **Maybe** `.+?`.